# gitlab-ci does not display environnement variable

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am working with gitlab-ci.

I have set an Environment variable: MY_ENV_VAR (in Project CI/CD Settings menu)

I see a message with says the environnement variable is prefixed by K8S_SECRET_

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy:
  only:
    - prod
  script:
    echo ${K8S_SECRET_MY_ENV_VAR}
```

It does not display the value in job... I see the echo command in green but i have something blank bellow.

I have tried echo $K8S_SECRET_MY_ENV_VAR or echo $SECRET_MY_ENV_VAR. It is the same.

Thanks

Comment: try env or printenv and check how the variables are stored

Comment: env does not display anything

Comment: which operation system is the gitlab runner on?

Comment: it is an ubuntu docker image

Comment: try printenv. if still nothing and this is shell executor try to write it to file printenv > /tmp/here... in my experience the name of the env is the same as the secret name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `K8S_SECRET_` prefix is to target variables for the [Auto Devops](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#auto-devops-application-variables) feature. [Normal variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#variables) need no such prefix, so in your example simply reference `$MY_ENV_VAR`